# Using Tasker to detect when a waypoint is reached in Google Maps

Tags: tasker, google-maps

I have an issue with my Google Maps app where it doesn’t always tell me that I have reached a waypoint. I have contacted support and they could not find any solution ([found here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/WGB9eJjKYPg;context-place=topicsearchin/maps/beetle120)).

So I am hoping that Tasker can help me. I have found that when I reach a waypoint that the Google Maps notification bar icon disappears so I am hoping that Tasker will be able to detect it and run a task.

While I have set up simple tasks before this is a bit out of my league so I am hoping that I could have some guidance setting this up. Or, if necessary, an alternate solution (Ideally fixing the original problem).